# java script error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: functions, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

i had a website that was working fine on localhost without any errors but after i uploaded it on the domain the slider stoped working and i got this errors

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL /js/jquery-ui.min.js:5
   Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function custom.js:33
   (anonymous function) custom.js:33 c jquery-latest.min.js:1069
   p.fireWith jquery-latest.min.js:1113 x.extend.ready
   jquery-latest.min.js:129 q jquery-latest.min.js:38
```

when i removed the custom.js page the error are removed but i need it so i could make the slider work but i

i found that the (anonymous function) can be solved by adding ; after the function but i still give me the same error

Comment: Are all of your .js files actually loading?

Comment: Maybe you should check the inline java script, and php generated code in your slider. Maybe it's depends on php version on server (Some people use `<?=` tag and this is available php >5.4). Sometimes php can generate to much whitespaces so it can be problem.